# Battery Indicator only show 70% during charging

Tags: menu, battery

The Battery Percentage Indicator on the menu bar only show 70% when charging. Is there something wrong with that? Or is the developer decide to make it 70% for charging default?

Comment: What is the output of the following command (I found it on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal)):

`upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT)`
Do the values differ?

Do you have problems with your battery?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, and is being tracked and worked on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1315434